# Correlated query: select where condition not max(condition in inner query)

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2000, aggregate-functions, exists

I am trying to select all the rows where the userName and groupId is duplicated, and the userId is not the max userId for that userName/groupId combination. Here is my code so far:

```
select *
from userTable u
where exists
    (select *
    from userTable u1
    where userName <> '' and userName is not null
    and u.userName = u1.userName and u.groupId = u1.groupId
    and u.userId <> max(u1.userId)
    group by userName, groupId
    having count(*) > 1)
order by userName
```

However, the line:

```
and u.userId <> u1.max(userId)
```

is giving me an error.

What is the right way to do this query?

Comment: A minor typo, `u1.max(userId)` should be `max(u1.userId)`, but I don't think that will solve the problem.

Comment: @Rubish- thanks! I'll edit it to fix the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  userName, groupId, MAX(userId) AS maxId
        FROM    userTable
        GROUP BY
                userName, groupId
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) q
JOIN    userTable u
ON      u.userName = q.userName
        AND u.groupId = q.groupId
        AND u.userId <> q.maxId
```

Comment: was typing out a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, I think:

```
select t.*
from dbo.UserTable t
join ( select userName , groupID , maxUserID = max(userID)
       from dbo.UserTable x
       group by userName , groupID
       having count(*) > 1
     ) dupes on dupes.userName  = t.userName
            and dupes.groupID   = t.groupID
            and dupes.maxUserID > t.userID
```